# Mysql server has gone away, serialization and lock wait errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have cron3min.php, cron10min.php, cron60min.php.

I am using PDO.

cron3min.php is very busy, each 3 minutes he

1. download xml feeds from feeder
2. parse downloaded feeds
3. store odds to odds table, fixtures to fixtures,baby tables

And there is about 50.000 - 500.000 rows each 3 minutes, so very often first cron request is not finished when other request from cron comes.

When i check my error log from catch i see:

```
2015-08-23 10:57:36exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/topoddsengine.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/topoddsengine.php(25): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM G...')
#1 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/cron5min.php(27): TopOdds->insertTopOdds()
#2 {main}2015-08-23 10:58:11exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/topoddsengine.php:25
```

also

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php(496): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php(468): XMLtoDB->fillMap('')
#2 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php(600): XMLtoDB->getMap('')
#3 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/cron10min.php(22): XMLtoDB->resultsToHistoric()
#4 {main}2015-08-24 09:33:31exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php:496
```

and

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php(742): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php(677): XMLtoDB->execHistoric(Object(PDOStatement), Object(SimpleXMLElement), Object(SimpleXMLElement), '2015-08-21 18:0...', 1, NULL, 'Albania: Superl...', Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'albania:', 'Partizani Tiran...', 2337556, 'Partizani Tiran...', NULL, 1, Object(SimpleXMLElement), NULL, NULL, NULL, '62: X. Sukaj; ', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Laci', 2337554, NULL, 1, Object(SimpleXMLElement), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'E. \xC3\x87ela; ', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'tipgin', Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#2 /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/cron10min.php(22): XMLtoDB->resultsToHistoric()
#3 {main}2015-08-23 18:18:17exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /home/27425-18594.cloudwaysapps.com/jcjdkdtaur/public_html/php/class.xmltodb.php:742
```

In cron3min.php are this functions:

```
$provider->getOdds();
$xmldb->sendOddsToDb();
$xmldb->sendFixturesToDb();
$xmldb->fillBaby();
$topOdds->insertTopOdds();

$xmldb->copyHAtoHandicap();

$con->close();
```

Most busy function is `$xmldb->sendOddsToDb();` and `$xmldb->copyHAtoHandicap();`

I will copy here just $xmldb->sendOddsToDb();, in each function i start transaction and commit it on end of function and close.

here is sendOddsToDb() and please check it and see just a mysql logic, there is something wrong, is good how i begin transaction ? Xml parsing takes about 1:30-2 minutes (most time takes 3 way part of code where i need to store handicaps in array), so maybe it is long connection opened or something...

```
function sendOddsToDb(){    
    try{
        $this->conn->connect();
        $this->PDO->beginTransaction();

        $countries = $this->OddCountries; 
        $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($this->insOdds);
        //$dbempty = $this->countRows('odds');
        //$this->clrLeagues();                  

        foreach($countries as $country){
         $path = "{$this->base}/feeds/odds/{$country}odds.xml";
         $odds_feed = $this->parser->parseFile($path);

            foreach($odds_feed->league as $league){ //za svaku ligu u fidu

                $fcountries = $this->filterCountries($league->attributes()->country);
                $subid = $league->attributes()->sub_id;

                $sportname = '';
                $sportid = 0;
                if($odds_feed->attributes()->sport == 'soccer' || $odds_feed->attributes()->sport == 'football'){
                    $sportname = 'football';
                    $sportid = 1;
                }
                else{
                    $sportname = NULL;
                }
                $lg2 = '';
                $lg = $league->attributes()->name;
                $ctr = $league->attributes()->country.':';
                if(!contains(strtolower($lg),strtolower($ctr))){
                    $lg2 = ucfirst($ctr) . ' ' . ucfirst($lg);  
                }
                else{
                    $lg2 = $league->attributes()->name;
                }

                $flg = $this->getMap2($lg2);
                $this->sendLeaguesToDb($league->attributes()->id, $flg ,$fcountries,$sportid,$subid,'tipgin');
                foreach($league->match as $match){ 

                    $dbdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($match->attributes()->date));
                    $updateddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($odds_feed->attributes()->updated));
                    $dbtime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($match->attributes()->time));

                    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($dbdate . $dbtime));   

                    $hteam = $this->getMap(toShort($match->home->attributes()->name));  
                    $ateam = $this->getMap(toShort($match->away->attributes()->name));  

                    $fixid = 0;
                    if($match->attributes()->id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                        if($match->attributes()->alternate_id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                            $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id_2;
                        }
                        else{
                            $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $fixid = $match->attributes()->id;
                    }       
                    //$m = $hteam . ' ' . $ateam;
                    //var_dump('MATCH: ' . $m . ' HTEAM: ' . mb_detect_encoding($hteam). ' ATEAM: ' . mb_detect_encoding($ateam));          
                    foreach ($match->odds as $odds) { 
                        //var_dump($odd);
                        foreach ($odds->type as $type) { 

                            foreach ($type->bookmaker as $bookmaker) { 
                                //$oldbook = ;
                                if($bookmaker->attributes()->name != 'BetClick'){
                                if($bookmaker->attributes()->name != 'Bodog'){
                                if($bookmaker->attributes()->name != 'YouWin'){
                                $homeodds = NULL;
                                $drawodds = NULL;
                                $awayodds = NULL;
                                $numodds = NULL;
                                $dbhandicap = NULL;
                                $id2 = '0';
                                $typename = $this->getMap2($type->attributes()->name);

                                $fbooks = $this->filterBooks($bookmaker->attributes()->name);   

                                if($typename == 'Over/Under' || $typename == 'Over/Under 1st Half' || $typename == 'Over/Under 2nd Half'){

                                    foreach ($bookmaker->total as $total) { //daj kvote za svaki mec

                                    $numodds = $total->attributes()->name;
                                    foreach($total->odd as $odd){
                                    switch ($odd->attributes()->name) {
                                        case 'Over':
                                            $homeodds = $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                        case 'Under':
                                            $awayodds = $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    $id2 = $numodds;
                                    //echo 'ID: ' . $match->attributes()->alternate_id_2 . $league->attributes()->country . " ODDS: {$homeodds} {$drawodds} {$awayodds} TYPE: {$typename}  BOOK: {$fbooks}  ID2: {$id2}" . "<br>";

                                    }

                                //echo "HOME TEAM: {$hteam} <BR>";
                                //echo "AWAY TEAM: {$ateam} <BR>";  


                                $this->execOdds($stmt, $fixid, $updateddate,
                                $typename, $fcountries,$league->attributes()->name,
                                $league->attributes()->id, $subid, $league->attributes()->cup,$sportname,
                                $hteam,$match->home->attributes()->id,
                                $ateam,$match->away->attributes()->id, $datetime, $dbdate,
                                $dbtime, $match->attributes()->status, $numodds,$homeodds,$drawodds,
                                $awayodds, $fbooks, $bookmaker->attributes()->id, $dbhandicap, $id2);
                                }
                                }

                                else if($typename == 'Handicap' || $typename == '3Way Handicap'){
                                $homeodds = array();
                                $drawodds = array();
                                $awayodds = array();
                                $arrhandicap = array();
                                $fhandicap = '';

                                foreach ($bookmaker->handicap as $handicap) { //daj kvote za svaki mec 
                                if (strpos($handicap->attributes()->name,'+') !== false) {
                                $fhandicap = str_replace('+','',$handicap->attributes()->name);                             
                                }else{
                                $fhandicap = $handicap->attributes()->name;
                                }
                                $newhandi = '';
                                foreach($handicap->odd as $odd){
                                        //$odd = $handicap->odd;
                                        switch ($odd->attributes()->name) {
                                        case '1':
                                            $newhandi = $fhandicap;
                                            $homeodds[(string)$newhandi] = 
                                            $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                        case 'X':
                                            $newhandi = $fhandicap;
                                            $drawodds[(string)$newhandi] = 
                                            $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;  
                                        case '2':
                                            if (strpos($fhandicap,'-') !== false) { //if negative 
                                                $newhandi = str_replace('-','',$fhandicap); //to positive
                                                //echo 'NEGATIVE - OLD: ' . $fhandicap . ' NEW: '.$newhandi . '<br>';
                                            }
                                            elseif($fhandicap=='0'){
                                                $newhandi = '0';
                                            }
                                            else{ //if positive
                                                $newhandi = '-' . $fhandicap; //to negative
                                                //echo 'POSITIVE - OLD: ' . $fhandicap . ' NEW: '.$newhandi . '<br>';
                                            }
                                            $awayodds[(string)$newhandi] = $odd->attributes()->value; 
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        $arrhandicap[] = $newhandi;
                                    }
                                }
                                //$arrhandicap[] = sort($dbhandicap);
                                foreach($arrhandicap as $hand){
                                if(!is_null($hand)){
                                //echo $typename. ': ' . $hand . '<br>';
                                if($homeodds[(string)$hand] != NULL && $awayodds[(string)$hand] != NULL){
                                $this->execOdds($stmt, $fixid, $updateddate,
                                $typename, $fcountries,$league->attributes()->name,
                                $league->attributes()->id, $subid, $league->attributes()->cup,$sportname,
                                $hteam,$match->home->attributes()->id,
                                $ateam,$match->away->attributes()->id, $datetime, $dbdate,
                                $dbtime, $match->attributes()->status, $numodds,$homeodds[(string)$hand],
                                $drawodds[(string)$hand],$awayodds[(string)$hand], $fbooks, 
                                $bookmaker->attributes()->id, $hand, $hand);
                                echo 'ID: ' . $match->attributes()->id . $league->attributes()->country . " HOMEODDS: {$homeodds[(string)$hand]}  DRAWODDS: {$drawodds[(string)$hand]}  AWAYODDS: {$awayodds[(string)$hand]} TYPE: {$typename}  BOOK: {$fbooks}  ID2: {$hand}" . "<br>";                                                    
                                }
                                }
                                }
                                }
                                else{
                                foreach ($bookmaker->odd as $odd) { //daj kvote za svaki mec
                                    if($typename == 'Home/Away'){
                                        $typename = 'Draw No Bet';
                                    }
                                    switch ($odd->attributes()->name) {
                                        case '1':
                                        case '1X':
                                        case 'Yes':
                                            $homeodds = $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                        case 'X':
                                        case 'X2':
                                            $drawodds = $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                        case '2':
                                        case '12':
                                        case 'No':
                                            $awayodds = $odd->attributes()->value;
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    $id2 = 0;
                                    //echo 'ID: ' . $match->attributes()->alternate_id_2 . $league->attributes()->country . " ODDS: {$homeodds} {$drawodds} {$awayodds} TYPE: {$typename}  BOOK: {$fbooks}  ID2: {$id2}" . "<br>";
                                  }

                                //echo "HOME TEAM: {$hteam} <BR>";
                                //echo "AWAY TEAM: {$ateam} <BR>";  

                                $this->execOdds($stmt, $fixid, $updateddate,
                                $typename, $fcountries,$league->attributes()->name,
                                $league->attributes()->id, $subid, $league->attributes()->cup,$sportname,
                                $hteam,$match->home->attributes()->id,
                                $ateam,$match->away->attributes()->id, $datetime, $dbdate,
                                $dbtime, $match->attributes()->status, $numodds,$homeodds,$drawodds,
                                $awayodds, $fbooks, $bookmaker->attributes()->id, $dbhandicap, $id2);

                                }
                            }
                            }
                            }
                        }}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->PDO->commit(); //SAVE
        $this->conn->close();
        $this->error = false;
        }
    catch(Exception $e){

    }
}
private function execOdds($stmt, $matchid, $upddate, $type, $country, $league, $leagueid, $subid, $cup, $sport, $hteam, $hteamid, $ateam, $ateamid, $datetime, $date, $time, $status, $numodds, $homeodds, $drawodds, $awayodds, $book, $bookid, $handicap, $id2){

    $event = $hteam . ' - ' . $ateam;

    $fcountry = $country;
    $fleague = $this->getMap2($league);

    $stmt->bindParam(':fixturematchid', $matchid);$stmt->bindParam(':updateddate',$upddate);$stmt->bindParam(':type',$type);
    $stmt->bindParam(':country',$fcountry);$stmt->bindParam(':league',$fleague);$stmt->bindParam(':leagueid',$leagueid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':subid',$subid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cup',$cup);$stmt->bindParam(':eventname',$event);$stmt->bindParam(':sportname',$sport);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hometeam', $hteam);$stmt->bindParam(':hometeamid', $hteamid);$stmt->bindParam(':awayteam', $ateam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayteamid', $ateamid);$stmt->bindParam(':datetime',$datetime);$stmt->bindParam(':date',$date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':time',$time);$stmt->bindParam(':status',$status);$stmt->bindParam(':numodds', $numodds);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeodds', $homeodds);$stmt->bindParam(':drawodds',$drawodds);$stmt->bindParam(':awayodds',$awayodds);
    $stmt->bindParam(':bookmaker',$book);$stmt->bindParam(':bookmakerid',$bookid);$stmt->bindParam(':handicap', $handicap);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id2', $id2);
    $stmt->execute(); //EXEC*/
}
```

Comment: Is solution to move connect/begin and commit/close inside execOdds, so it will connect/begin and commit/close for each odd

Answer (score 1):

As you have getting in error logs that some query is try to lock the record while other one is already using it by lock. There can be various reasons, so try to check with them and resolved the issue.

First Step:

As you updating in your post that cron is taking more than 3 minutes and next round is starting, so may be first time cron is using some record and 2nd time cron also try to lock it.

But it can be only if your query is not using index properly and trying to lock more records than expected. so check your queries if can be optimize.

Second Step:

May be some other process also trying to lock the row at which time this cron is executing, so check details in engine innodb status that which process is creating deadlock.

You can also monitor by any gui tool like mysqladmin what queries are trying to acquire lock at the time of this cron and optimize query/code where this is happening.